# JavaScript to change background color of class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I feel like I am banging my head against a brick wall here and cant figure out what I have done wrong, I have written some JS to pick a random color from an array and then I want to change the color of class to that color:

I have tried changing the class to just `class="button1"` aswell but still nothing, I have also added in alerts and everything seems to be passed through ok until the last line of `changeElementColor` when nothing happens.

Also, I would prefer if I could use something like `changeElementColor(this.element)` instead of typing it into the HTML, is that possible?

```js
    var colorArray = ["#aa3333", "#33aa33", "#3333aa", "#aaaa33", "#33aaaa", "#aa33aa", "#aa6633", "#66aa33", "#33aa66"];
    
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    function chooseRandomColor() {
    var randomInt = getRandomInt(0,colorArray.length);
    return colorArray[randomInt];    
    }

    function changeElementColor(elementString) {
    alert(elementString);
    var obj = document.getElementsByClassName(elementString);
    alert(obj);
    var color = chooseRandomColor();
    alert(color)
    obj.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
```

```css
    [class^="button"] {
    background-color: #333333;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    }
    
    [class^="button"] span {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; 
    }
    
    .button1 {
    background-color: #3333ff;
    }
    
    .sm-sq-butt {
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    }
    
    .md-sq-butt {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    }
```

```html
 <a href="#"><div onclick="changeElementColor('button1')" class="button1 md-sq-butt"><span>HOME</span></div></a>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [collection of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not 1 element so `obj.style` will not be available.

So you need to access each element in the collection and change the style(using a loop).

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    obj[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0qjc6khw/)

Comment: Thanks, so as I understand this. For the above code, the collection is only 1 item, if I have other `class="button1"` on the page this would go through all of the elements and change the color! :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following.

I have used jQuery events and selector to get this all done in short lines.

```js
var colorArray = ["#aa3333", "#33aa33", "#3333aa", "#aaaa33", "#33aaaa", "#aa33aa", "#aa6633", "#66aa33", "#33aa66"];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function chooseRandomColor() {
var randomInt = getRandomInt(0,colorArray.length);
return colorArray[randomInt];    
}


$('.button1').click(function(){
  changeElementColor('.button1');
});

function changeElementColor(elementString) {
alert(elementString);
  var color = chooseRandomColor();
  $(elementString).css('background-color',color);
  

}
```

```css
[class^="button"] {
background-color: #333333;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
color: #aaaaaa;
text-align: center;
display: table;
}

[class^="button"] span {
display: table-cell; 
vertical-align: middle; 
text-align: center; 
}

.button1 {
background-color: #3333ff;
}

.sm-sq-butt {
font-size: 10px;
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
}

.md-sq-butt {
font-size: 20px;
height: 120px;
width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><div class="button1 md-sq-butt"><span>HOME</span></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your javascript slightly and this should work.

```js
var colorArray = ["#aa3333", "#33aa33", "#3333aa", "#aaaa33", "#33aaaa", "#aa33aa", "#aa6633", "#66aa33", "#33aa66"];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function chooseRandomColor() {
  var randomInt = getRandomInt(0, colorArray.length);
  return colorArray[randomInt];
}

changeElementColor = function(elementString) {
  console.log(elementString);
  var obj = document.getElementsByClassName(elementString);
  console.log(obj);
  var color = chooseRandomColor();
  console.log(color)
  obj[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
[class^="button"] {
  background-color: #333333;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
[class^="button"] span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: #3333ff;
}
.sm-sq-butt {
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
.md-sq-butt {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div onclick="changeElementColor('button1')" class="button1 md-sq-butt"><span>HOME</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the color of the class when clicked. A simple way of doing this would be to use the `this` keyword on click of the element and pass that into the `changeElementColor` function.

`onclick="changeElementColor(this)"`

and then access that in:

```
function changeElementColor(elementString) {
var color = chooseRandomColor();
elementString.style.color = color //Changes the text color
elementString.style.backgroundColor = color //Changes the background color
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k1s0zng5/3/